# How is time notated for the overlapping hour when switching to daylight savings?

Tags: time

How is time notated for the overlapping hour when switching to daylight savings?

At
1:59:59 AM (#1) -- daylight saving time in effect.

Then clocks get turned back to:

1:00:00 -- standard time.

Almost an hour later:
1:59:59 AM (#2)

So how does one denote the difference between the first and second instances of 1:59:59 AM?

(Is this an English question? ... a question of notation?)

Comment: It’s not a physics question because physicists use time systems that don’t have this kind of pathology.

Comment: I'd say it's a question of notation, so I think it's valid to ask it here. OTOH, any experimentalist who could face this issue probably should avoid  it by using UTC. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about civix (nonscientific) time notation, not physics.

Comment: "I'd say it's a question of notation, so I think it's valid to ask it here."
"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about civix (nonscientific) time notation, not physics."

Ok... what is the topic correct for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how does one denote the difference between the first and second instances of 1:59:59 AM?

Either use a time standard such as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), or even better, International Atomic Time (TAI), that does not suffer this ambiguity, or include the time zone in the timestamp. For example on the night of the shift from daylight savings time to standard time, one would record the first occurrence of 1:59:59 AM as 01:59:59 CDT (o.r 01:59:59 -5) ands the second occurrence as 01:59:59 CST (or 01:59:59 -6).

Comment: #1 standard, #2 DST or daylight savings time